# Issues with script run from /etc/rc.local

Tags: bash, debian, raspbian

I'm trying to run a bash script at boot time from /etc/rc.local on a headless Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian buster lite - Debian based).  I've done something similar on a Pi 3 with success so I'm confused about why the Pi 4 would misbehave - or behave differently.
The script executed from /etc/rc.local fires but appears to just exit at seemingly random intervals with no indication as to why it's being terminated.

To test it, I dumbed down the script and just stuck the following into a test script called /home/pi/test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2> /tmp/output      # send stderr from rc.local to a log file
exec 1>&2                # send stdout to the same log file
set -x                   # tell bash to display commands before execution

while true
do
        echo 'Still alive'
        sleep .1
done
```

I then call it from /etc/rc.local just before the exit line:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local - executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel
#
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.

/home/pi/test.sh
echo $? >/tmp/exiterr #output exit code to /tmp/exiterr

exit 0
```

The contents of /tmp/output:

```
+ true
+ echo 'Still alive'
Still alive
+ sleep .1
+ true
+ echo 'Still alive'
Still alive
+ sleep .1
```

and /tmp/exiterr shows

```
0
```

If I reduce the sleep period, /tmp/output is longer (over 6000 lines without the sleep).
Any ideas why the script is exiting shortly after starting?

Comment: That may have to do with the specifics of `/etc/rc.local` on rasbain. You may consider asking on [**Raspberry pi StackExchange**](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) if you don't get a definite answer here.

Comment: Belongs to [Raspberry pi StackExchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I wondered about that, though I have a Raspberry Pi 3 on the same OS that doesn't appear to have this issue.